# ViewPanel: DisplayAsLink removes totals

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages

I just noticed when working with a xp:viewPanel which displays a view containing totals. These totals are not displayed when the column is set to 'display as link'.

Could someone explain to me why this is happening? Or what the fix would be to work around this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm seeing is that the column totals for category rows disappear when the column is set to display as links. This is what you are seeing, right?
This may appear to be an issue at first glance, though more likely to be a software limitation - working as designed. 
Category totals don't refer to a specific document so it makes sense in a way not to put links there for these rows. Elsewhere it makes sense as those rows refer to documents. 
 
However, maybe category totals should display regardless and not have the links applied by the runtime. This would be an enhancement request.

Comment: I think I would go for your last lines. Category totals should be displayed regardless the case. Now I had to disable the displayaslink property on the total columns which also has the side effet that the data in this column which is not a total are not displayed as link and therefore we get a stange behaviour.